# How to shorten this MySQL Query (colums use often the same sql parts...)

Tags: mysql

I am not an MySQL Professinal, but my query works fine

```
SELECT r.id,

    /* Total repurchase price per Ton
     * (Quantitiy/t * repurchase price/dry) + Extra Costs
     */
     (
    SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * (rw.preis / (IF (rw.is_zement = 1, 1.25 , 1)) / (1 - (IFNULL(rw.h2o, 0) / 100)))) +
    SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * pr.preis) +
    IF ((r.extra_1_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_1_type = 1), extra_1 , extra_1 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0) +
    IF ((r.extra_2_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_2_type = 1), extra_2 , extra_2 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0) +
    IF ((r.finanzierung_satz > 0) AND (r.finanzierung_monate > 0) AND SUM(rc.menge / 1000),
    ((r.finanzierung_satz / 100) / 12) * r.finanzierung_monate * (
        SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * (rw.preis / (IF (rw.is_zement = 1, 1.25 , 1)) / (1 - (IFNULL(rw.h2o, 0) / 100)))) +
        SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * pr.preis) +
        IF ((r.extra_1_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_1_type = 1), extra_1 , extra_1 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0) +
        IF ((r.extra_2_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_2_type = 1), extra_2 , extra_2 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0)
    )
    , 0) )  as repurchase_price,

    /* Profit
     * (Quantitiy/t * Price) - repurchase_price
     */
    (SUM(rc.menge) / 1000 * r.vk) - (

    SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * (rw.preis / (IF (rw.is_zement = 1, 1.25 , 1)) / (1 - (IFNULL(rw.h2o, 0) / 100)))) +
    SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * pr.preis) +
    IF ((r.extra_1_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_1_type = 1), extra_1 , extra_1 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0) +
    IF ((r.extra_2_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_2_type = 1), extra_2 , extra_2 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0) +
    IF ((r.finanzierung_satz > 0) AND (r.finanzierung_monate > 0) AND SUM(rc.menge / 1000),
    ((r.finanzierung_satz / 100) / 12) * r.finanzierung_monate * (
        SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * (rw.preis / (IF (rw.is_zement = 1, 1.25 , 1)) / (1 - (IFNULL(rw.h2o, 0) / 100)))) +
        SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * pr.preis) +
        IF ((r.extra_1_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_1_type = 1), extra_1 , extra_1 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0) +
        IF ((r.extra_2_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_2_type = 1), extra_2 , extra_2 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0)
    )
    , 0)

    ) as profit,

    /* Profit Percentage
     * Profit / (repurchase_price / 100)
     */
    ((SUM(rc.menge) / 1000 * r.vk) - (

    SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * (rw.preis / (IF (rw.is_zement = 1, 1.25 , 1)) / (1 - (IFNULL(rw.h2o, 0) / 100)))) +
    SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * pr.preis) +
    IF ((r.extra_1_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_1_type = 1), extra_1 , extra_1 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0) +
    IF ((r.extra_2_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_2_type = 1), extra_2 , extra_2 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0) +
    IF ((r.finanzierung_satz > 0) AND (r.finanzierung_monate > 0) AND SUM(rc.menge / 1000),
    ((r.finanzierung_satz / 100) / 12) * r.finanzierung_monate * (
        SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * (rw.preis / (IF (rw.is_zement = 1, 1.25 , 1)) / (1 - (IFNULL(rw.h2o, 0) / 100)))) +
        SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * pr.preis) +
        IF ((r.extra_1_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_1_type = 1), extra_1 , extra_1 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0) +
        IF ((r.extra_2_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_2_type = 1), extra_2 , extra_2 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0)
    )
    , 0)

    ))

    /

    ((

    SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * (rw.preis / (IF (rw.is_zement = 1, 1.25 , 1)) / (1 - (IFNULL(rw.h2o, 0) / 100)))) +
    SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * pr.preis) +
    IF ((r.extra_1_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_1_type = 1), extra_1 , extra_1 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0) +
    IF ((r.extra_2_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_2_type = 1), extra_2 , extra_2 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0) +
    IF ((r.finanzierung_satz > 0) AND (r.finanzierung_monate > 0) AND SUM(rc.menge / 1000),
    ((r.finanzierung_satz / 100) / 12) * r.finanzierung_monate * (
        SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * (rw.preis / (IF (rw.is_zement = 1, 1.25 , 1)) / (1 - (IFNULL(rw.h2o, 0) / 100)))) +
        SUM((rc.menge / 1000) * pr.preis) +
        IF ((r.extra_1_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_1_type = 1), extra_1 , extra_1 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0) +
        IF ((r.extra_2_type > 0), IF ((r.extra_2_type = 1), extra_2 , extra_2 * SUM(rc.menge / 1000)) , 0)
    )
    , 0)
    ) / 100)

    as profit_percentage,

FROM recipe as r
LEFT JOIN recipecomponent as rc ON r.id = rc.recipe_id
LEFT JOIN rawmaterial as rw ON rc.rawmaterial_id = rw.id
LEFT JOIN press as pr ON r.press_id = pr.id
GROUP BY r.id
ORDER BY lieferdatum desc
```

As you can see, to calculate price, profit, profit percentage, I use often
the same parts... Is it possible to shorten my SQL Query? To make it more
'elegant' :)

Thank you & Best Regars Simon

Comment: Code optimization/reduction is off-topic. We fix problems, we don't optimize things.

Comment: You could try to write a stored functions for your duplicated code http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-function/. By using a function name and parameters, you could gain in readability in a big query like this (and you could reuse your functions in other queries).

Comment: @JonathanParentLévesque and make it a tad slower.

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) folks *might* deal with query optimization.

Comment: Yes, improving SQL queries is on-topic on Code Review, as long as the query works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a generic answer, if you repeat caculations in your query, you can use derived tables to avoid repetition:

```
select d.a, d.b, d.a*d.b
from (
  select x+y+z as a, d+e+f as b
  from yourtable
) as d;
```